# Webpack LESS . background image issue

Tags: css, webpack, less

Hello I have seen few forums talking about this, and lots of suggestions but not a clear solution, at least one with an explanation. I am having issues loading a background image using LESS Loader in Webpack.

```
`publicPath: './bin/'`
`loader: extractLESS.extract('css?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]!less')`
```

The issue is that if I inspect the class I get the path non resolved, just as typed on LESS file.

```
`.secondComponent__imagen___2-dKX {
        color: black;
        background-image: url(/rock.png);
}`
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the source code of your CSS that's generating this output?

Answer (score -1):

Using a LESS function to convert the image prevents it from using path.

`background-image: data-uri('image/jpeg;base64','./rock.jpg');`